# Extending of domain of smooth function of two variables

Tags: analysis

Let $f: [a,b]\times [c,d] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a smooth function of two variable (assuming that in boundary points $f$ has continuous one side partial derivatives).

Is a simple way to extend $f$  to a smooth function $F: \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can assume that $a=c=0$ and $b=d=1$. Then define $f_1(x,y)=f(-x,y)$ for $x\in [-1,0]$ and $y\in [0,1]$ (it will have continuous partial derivatives. Then define $f_2(x,-y)=f_1(x,y)$ for $y\in [-1,0]$ to extend the map to $[-1,1]\times [-1,1]$. Now we can repeat this procedure to extend the map to a smooth one on $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: I don't see how to extend $f$ beyond $[-1,1] \times [-1,1]$ using this procedure. For example, how would we define $f$ on $[1,2] \times [1,2]$?